How to manage ViewModels used in multple SwiftUI Views with EnvironmentObject or @StateObject and @ObservedObject
I'm a little confused on when to use @StateObject/@ObservedObject  and when to use @EnvironmentObject.  My confusing is for when the same ViewModel needs to be used in multiple views. For instance, the code below, I need to use SomeViewModel in all four tab views. In fact, in my current app I'm injecting all my ViewModels to the @EnvironmentObjet as shown in Method 2 below, but I recenlty ran into an issue where some UI controls were not showing and realized that by removing the calls to the view models solves the issue so, I'm now wondering if @StateObject/@ObservedObject is the right choice but after thinking about it, the way I'm showing in Method 1, I'm creating multiple instances of the SomeViewModel and got me wondering if I will end up running into different issues.
What is the most recommended way to use the same viewModel class in multiple SwiftUI views?
View Model Class
class SomeViewModel: ObservableObject{
    // some Published variables
    // creates, edits, deletes for Core Data objects
}

METHOD 1
Using @StateObject and @ObservedObject example:
    struct MainView: View {
        
        var body: some View {
            TabView(){

                TabViewOne()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "cart.fill")
                    Text("Tab1")
                }.tag(0)

                TabViewTwo()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "note.text")
                    Text("Tab2")
                }.tag(1)

                TabViewThree()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "tag.fill")
                    Text("Tab3")
                }.tag(3)

                TabViewFour()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "gear")
                    Text("Tab4")
                }.tag(4)
            }
        }
    }

Tab View One
    struct TabViewOne: View {
        @StateObject var someViewModel = SomeViewModel()

        var body: some View {
            // passs someViewModel to children views
            DetailView(someViewModel: someViewModel)
        }
    }

    struct DetailView: View {
        @ObservedObject var someViewModel: SomeViewModel
        var body: some View {
            // use someViewModel 
        }
    }

Tab View Two
    struct TabViewTwo: View {
        @StateObject var someViewModel = SomeViewModel()

        var body: some View {
            // passs someViewModel to children views
            DetailView(someViewModel: someViewModel)
        }
    }

    struct DetailView2: View {
        @ObservedObject var someViewModel: SomeViewModel
        var body: some View {
            // use someViewModel 
        }
    }

The same thing is done for the rest of tab views.
METHOD 2
Injecting the view model to the @EnvironmentObject in the first view of the app example:
    @main
    struct MyAppName: SwiftUI.App {
        
        @StateObject var someViewModel: SomeViewModel

        var body: some Scene {
            WindowGroup {
                MainView()
                    .environmentObject(someViewModel)
            }
        }
    }

Tab View One
    struct TabViewOne: View {
        @EnvironmentObject private var someViewModel: SomeViewModel

        var body: some View {
            // use someViewModel here
        }
    }

    struct DetailView: View {
        @EnvironmentObject private var someViewModel: SomeViewModel

        var body: some View {
            // use someViewModel here
        }
    }

Tab View Two
    struct TabViewTwo: View {
        @EnvironmentObject private var someViewModel: SomeViewModel

        var body: some View {
            // use someViewModel here
        }
    }

    struct DetailView2: View {
        @EnvironmentObject private var someViewModel: SomeViewModel

        var body: some View {
            // use someViewModel here
        }
    }

The same thing is done for the rest of tab views.
Just give you more context, SomeViewModel contains all the creates, edits and deletes for TabViewOne and the rest of views are only referencing one or two functions from it, but the heavy user is TabViewOne.
Thanks

IMO if your views can share view model, then either your view model holds too much (and is no longer a view model, but something else - a service maybe), or your views are not really separate views, but some variations of the same view.

@timbretimbre - Very good point, in fact, that's something I have been debating myself if I'm structuring my code correctly. For instance, let's say in my TabViewOne I'm creating, deleting and editing Dogs, I would create a DogViewModel and use it directly there, now what if in TabViewTwo I need to reference dog.breed, how would you extract the breed from DogViewModel? Thanks

Breed would be a data model so you would need to have some data source for dog and breed that all your view models can access.

So, you could create a Dog class that can be used in all views and a DogViewModel class which will only be accessed by TabViewOne? If this is correct, what info would you normally add to each class? Thanks.

You need to learn State and Binding. If you try to use view model objects you'll run into major issues.

@malhal -  So, none of the two *Methods I posted in my original question would you recommend?

@fs_tigre neither of those methods are standard SwiftUI

Any source I can reference to learn about view models in SwiftUI? I feel like my strongest misunderstanding is structuring my code.

See Apple official docs Monitoring data. Simply copy and paste the example code. Also look at the newer way using @Observable, Managing model data in your app for iOS17+. These are the Apple recommended ways to use the same dataModel class in multiple SwiftUI views.

@workingdogsupportUkraine - Thanks a lot for the good, referenced articles.
